# Angularjs 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: angularjs

I have this following code. I tried to access the link in rest client using my browser and its working fine. my problem is when i try to access it in my angular app it returns an error bad request, Why?

my Api was made of laravel. the auth/access_token requires a Post method, and json header, also it returns a json value

```
 $http.post(api + "auth/access_token",
          {
             username      : username,
             password      : password,
             grant_type    : 'password',
             client_id     :'54321',
             client_secret :'terces'
          })
            .then(function (result) {
                userInfo = {
                    accessToken: result.data.access_token,
                    userName: result.data.userName
                };
                $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
                deferred.resolve(userInfo);
            }, function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
```

**

> http://api.localsite.dev/auth/access_token 400 (Bad Request)

**

Comment: are you creating the form using laravel like `@form(..` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generate the form using laravel it implecitly generates csrf token for the form as a hidden input. And then if you are validating that token in the backend after submission there can be a server error because there is no token in the POST request